# How to determine a group association based on columns from list with corresponding information at least 2 out of 5 times?

Tags: r, grouping

I have a list that refers to 5 columns

```
list<-c("Last Name","First Name", "Email","Address", "Phone Number")
```

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID|First Name|Last Name|First Name|Email             |Address           |Phone
 1 Wayne     Bruce      BWayne@gmail.com   1995 Gotham Avenue 111-111-1111 
 2 Kent      Clark      Ckent@Yahoo.com    200 Kryptonite St  222-222-2222
 3 Wayne                                   200 Kryptonite St
 4 Parker    Peter      PParker@gmail.com  100 Mae Road       333-333-3333
 4 Wayne     Bruce
 5 Parker                                                     333-333-3333
 6 Murdock   Matthew    MMurdock@hotmai.com 100 Main Road     444-444-4444
 7 Wayne
```

How to organize the dataset like this

```
 ID|First   |Last Name|First Name|Email             |Address           |Phone  |Group
 1 Wayne     Bruce      BWayne@gmail.com   1995 Gotham Avenue 111-111-1111 1
 2 Kent      Clark      Ckent@Yahoo.com    200 Kryptonite St  222-222-2222 2
 3 Wayne                                   200 Kryptonite St               1
 4 Parker    Peter      PParker@gmail.com  100 Mae Road       333-333-3333 3
 4 Wayne     Bruce                                                         1
 5 Parker                                                     333-333-3333 3
 6 Murdock   Matthew    MMurdock@hotmai.com 100 Main Road     444-444-4444 4
 7 Wayne                                                                   5
```

Note that the last Wayne is not associated with the first Wayne because it only has one column in common with the other times there is Wayne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `match`.  We `paste` the subset of columns by row with `do.call`, then use that to `match` with those `unique` values to get the index

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, df1[list])
df1$Group <- match(v1, unique(v1))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(list))) %>%
    mutate(Group = cur_group_id())
```

---

If we want to remove the `NA`, use `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(list), na_if, "")) %>%
    unite(grp, all_of(list), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Group = match(grp, unique(grp)), grp = NULL)
```